# How to trigger Github actions workflow whenever a new tag was pushed?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, github-actions

Whenever a pull request was merged into the main branch I'm calling a Github action workflow that creates a new tag

```
name: Create new tag on push on main branch

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'main'

permissions:
  contents: write

jobs:
  create-new-tag:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Get next version # checks if conventional commit would cause a new version
        id: get_next_version
        uses: thenativeweb/get-next-version@2.5.0

      - name: Create new tag
        if: ${{ steps.get_next_version.outputs.hasNextVersion == 'true' }}
        run: |
          git tag ${{steps.get_next_version.outputs.version}}
          git push origin ${{steps.get_next_version.outputs.version}}
```

This workflow is working as expected. I want to create a second workflow that triggers, whenever a new tag has been created. It should build the application and release the binaries on Github. I started with

```
name: Release binaries for new tag

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - '*'

jobs:
  release-binaries:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      # I think this step makes sense to ensure the build always matches the git tag
      - name: Checkout new tag
        run: git checkout ${{ github.ref_name }}

      - name: Next step
        run: echo "next ..."
```

Unfortunately this workflow never runs, so it doesn't seem to trigger. When I make a change on Github and push with

> feat: a change

the minor version would increase so a new tag is created. But that won't trigger the second workflow afterwards.

Is something wrong or did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand what happens: when you make a push in a Github Action workflow without informing any token, the `GITHUB_TOKEN` is used as default.

However, according to the [Github Official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#triggering-a-workflow-from-a-workflow)

> When you use the repository's `GITHUB_TOKEN` to perform tasks, events triggered by the `GITHUB_TOKEN`, with the exception of workflow_dispatch and repository_dispatch, will not create a new workflow run. **This prevents you from accidentally creating recursive workflow runs.**

The solution is the following recommendation:

> If you do want to trigger a workflow from within a workflow run, you can use a **personal access token** instead of `GITHUB_TOKEN` to trigger events that require a token. You'll need to create a personal access token and store it as a secret.

[Here is how to create a Personal Access Token (PAT)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)

---

Therefore, in your case, you should create a PAT and use it in your workflow.

When informed using the `actions/checkout`, the PAT should persist for the other steps within the same job, so using the following implementation in your first workflow should resolve the problem.

```yaml
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Is it possible to simply use the Github actions bot? Found usage here https://github.com/thenativeweb/get-next-version/blob/main/.github/workflows/release.yml#L50 the action is using the Github actions bot https://github.com/EndBug/add-and-commit/blob/main/src/io.ts#L171 and the checkout action has an example as well https://github.com/actions/checkout#push-a-commit-using-the-built-in-token

Comment: Based on https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/13 I tried `- name: Setup Git user run: | git config user.name github-actions git config user.email github-actions@github.com` for the tagging workflow but that didn't help

Comment: Even if you set the user, the problem is related to the workflow scope permission. Without using a PAT, you won't be able to trigger a new workflow run from the current one.